# Why does overloading ++ take significantly longer than incrementing just the value?

Tags: c#, operator-overloading

Why does incrementing an (in my case) Uint by one 100.000.000 times take ~0.175 seconds, while incrementing an Uint within a struct the same amount of times takes ~1.21 seconds?

The tests have been conducted roughly 10 times with nearly the same results in time. If it can't be helped, so be it. But I would like to know what causes this. The time increase is rather significant. The operator overload below is the exact code used:

```
private uint _num;        
public static Seq operator ++(Seq a)
{
    a._num++; return a;
}
```

I chose to edit the instance itself (if this goes against guidelines) rather than returning a new instance because this also takes quite a while longer.

This struct will be incremented very frequently, thus I'm looking for the reason to this increased processing time.

Comment: `Seq` is a struct?

Comment: @vasily.sib Yes, it is.

Comment: How big is Seq?  `return a` will likely result in at least once copy operation on a `struct`.  Have you tried to see what happens if you make Seq a `class`?

Comment: @Flydog57 It only contains that 1 UInt. Turning it into a class gives roughly the same result (even slightly more). Since this is only 4 bytes anyway I was looking to avoid the extra overhead that comes with a class

Comment: That makes sense.  I wouldn't have thought it would 7x longer (1.21 / 0.175 = about 7).  But, now I'm reading @ericLippert's explanation (which I'm assuming is pretty close to right)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's simply a matter of how smart the jitter is.  For a regular local int variable, the statement

```
x++;
```

can in many cases be reduced to a *single machine instruction* because the local variable could be enregistered. If it is not enregistered then the sequence of instructions will be to load the value, increment it, and store it, so a handful of instructions.

But overloading `++` on a struct has the following semantics. Suppose we have our struct in `s` and we say `s++`.  That means effectively that we implement

```
s = S.operator++(s);
```

What does that do?

1. Make a copy from `s` to the local variable location that is the new formal parameter
2. Stores away any register state that is going to be overwritten by the callee
3. execute the call instruction
4. load the value of the formal, increment it, store it
5. copy the new value to the location reserved for the return value
6. execute the return instruction
7. restore the state of the previous activation frame
8. copy the returned value to the location for `s`.

So your fast program is doing step 4. Your slow program is doing steps 1 through 8, and is about eight times slower.  The jitter could identify that this is a candidate for inlining and get rid of some of those costs, but it is by no means required to, and there are plenty of reasons why it might choose not to inline.  The jitter does not know that this increment is important to you.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, thanks! Does this mean that there's nothing that can be done to prevent this kind of performance loss?

Comment: @Dennis19901: You're building an abstraction; the purpose of an abstraction is to reduce the cost of understanding how code works to the developer; the price you pay is often a decrease in performance. If what you need more than anything else is performance, then start stripping away expensive abstractions and get closer to the machine.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is because your `Seq` is a struct (value-type) and a way increment operator works. As you can see `public static Seq operator ++(Seq a) { ... }` is **returning** an instance of your `Seq` struct. However, as structs are passed by value, it actually creates a new instance of `Seq` which is returned and here is your overhead.

Take a look at another example:

```
struct SeqStruct
{
    private uint _num;        
    public void Increment() => _num++;
}

// ----------------------------------

var seq = new SeqStruct();
var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++)
    seq.Increment();
s3.Stop();
```

Now, if you measure a time of invokation of `Increment()` method you may see that it is now closer to "pure" uint incrementation, and if you switch to **Release** build configuration, you will have same time as "pure" uint incrementation (this method was "inlined").

Another option is to use `class` instead of `struct`:

```
class SeqClass
{
    private uint _num;
    public static SeqClass operator ++(SeqClass a) { a._num++; return a; }
}
```

Now incrementation will do faster too.

Comment: You have a mondegreen! The method was **inlined**, not **one-lined**.  A method is *inlined* when the jitter realizes that the body of the method is small enough that you can replace the call with the method body, and therefore save on all the costs of the call setup and teardown.

Answer (score 0):

First off, that is the kind of question that calls for linking the performance rant: https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/ These kind of questions fall into premature optimisation/does not really mater territory.

As for the reason why: Aside from issues with measuring properly, there is at least a function call Overhead. It does not mater how far you are removed from naked pointers, internally there is still two [jump](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zR8V0lq029c) and a add/retrieve from the function stack happening.

Or at least it happens most of the time. The thing is that the JiT could go and [inline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_expansion) that function call. It might even partially recompile to make this change. It is really hard to predict if and when it does that.

Comment: I respect your concern for premature optimizations, but I'm working on some real-time processing and I'd rather not spend unnecessary time on a mundane task such as this if I could have done it otherwise.


That aside, with the "function call" are you referring to the overload itself or the actual increment of the UInt? It makes sense if this overhead comes from the overload function call, though I'm surprised at how much this overhead is.

Comment: @Dennis19901 : If you are doing realtime computing, the .NET Framework is a dead end anyway. Just the GC alone is usually a disqualifier. For this kind of performance you have to handle naked poitners on the Assembler, C, or native C++ level. Anything else has too much overhead, too many implied runtime checks.

Comment: I'm well aware. I've not took the time to pick up C++, but that will be the next project. Designing a real time network library combined with a foreign language doesn't seem like such a good idea. I will switch to C++ after this is done.

Comment: @Dennis19901 Native C++, not C++ .NET. The kind where handling naked pointer is the norm, not the exception that requires a switch. C++ .NET is closer related to C# then native C++.

Comment: I know the difference, and was playing to stay far away from VC++

Comment: You can do reasonably real-time processing in .NET if you are *real* careful. That code that you have should not have any "function call overhead" on a production build.  I would expect that the JIT will optimize that away for you as @Christopher pointed out.  Have you made sure that you don't have anything weird going on - you shouldn't be seeing a 7x time difference.  Take a look at your benchmark code to see if there's nothing silly happening, that everything is non-debug, etc.

Comment: It is certainly true that .NET is not suitable for realtime processing. But also **Windows** is not suitable for realtime processing. You only get a thread for something like 16 milliseconds! Windows makes very few of the guarantees that you need to ensure timely processing of messages or interrupts or any of that stuff.

Comment: @EricLippert: I propably should ahve linked the Wikipedia article on Realtime Programming. Indeed, let's do that now: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_computing